# Is it possible to convert (frequency, amplitude)-data to the corresponding (audio) sound in Python?

Tags: python, audio, fft, physics

I am working on a Python project simulating the sounds produced by vibrating strings. If for a given string, I have determined the Fourier transform of the motion, those results can by a simple operation be changed into the data showing the amplitude per (audio) frequency.

Is it possible to then turn those (frequency, amplitude)-data into the corresponding sound using Python?

I have tried it using IPython.display.audio but didn't manage to get it working properly.

Comment: Is your issue transforming the fft to a waveform, playing back the waveform, or storing the waveform? Are you using numpy for the fft? Can you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us where you get stuck? In its current state this question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Lanting. You made me reconsider what the waveform inherently meant, and I figured that I could work around using the fft (instead of doing a Fourier transform, executing certain operations followed by an inverse Fourier transform, I could directly apply the required operations on the original data). So thanks, although it might not have been exactly as you intended your reply ;)

Comment: I rolled my own code to synthesize audio from a collection of of input specs each with ( frequency, amplitude, phase shift ) which is the inverse fourier transform ... let us know how you get on using an api versus crafting your own solution

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly,you can extract and convert a specific (frequency, amplitude)-data into wav file with `scipy.io.wavfile.write`. Just don't forget to convert your array to [sample,channel] format.